# Determine size of Integer Binary Tree via recursion

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have the classes BinaryTreeNode(int value) with its left and right child and BinaryTree(int rootVal) with BinaryTreeNode root with rootVal as its value. 
I developed a code to calculate the number of nodes in the tree (in class BinaryTreeNode), but it doesn't work because of a NullPointerException:

```
public int size(){
    if(this == null) {    // base case
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + left.size() + right.size();
    }
}
```

However another solution I found, with a similar strategy, works:

```
public int size(BinaryTreeNode refNode){
    if(refNode == null) {    // base case
        return 0;       
    } else {
        return 1 + size(refNode.left) + size(refNode.right); 
    }
}
```

I have understood why my code throws an exception (it is because left/right would point to null).
But I would like to understand why the second solution works with quasi the same principle.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The second version works because you do not try to call a method on null, you just pass null to the function. And from the first if you know that refNode is not  null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example you try to find the size before you check for `null`:

first you call

```
left.size()
```

and then inside the `size()` method you check to see if the object you just called the method on is `null`

```
if(this == null) {    // base case
    return 0;
...
```

so if `left` is `null`, you get the NPE before you get into the `size()` method.

The main thing to remember here, is that `this` can **never** be `null`.  If it was, you couldn't be running a method on it in the first place.  So you weren't actually terminating your recursion on a `null` case like you thought you were.

In the second you check for `null` first:

if refNode.left is `null` here

```
    return 1 + size(refNode.left) + size(refNode.right);
```

the `size()` method does a pre-check

```
if(refNode == null) {    // base case
    return 0;
...
```

and safely returns `0`.

You could make your first method work by explicitly putting the null-check first on each branch:

```
public int size(){
    return 1 
        + left == null ? 0 : left.size()    // check for null first
        + right == null ? 0 : right.size(); // check for null first
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The base case is organized in the wrong way; checking for `null` on the current instance makes no sense. The method should be rewritten as follows.

```
public int size(){
    int sizeLeft = 0;
    if (this.left != null)
        sizeLeft = left.size();
    int sizeRight = 0;
    if (this.right != null)
        sizeRight = right.size();
    return 1 + sizeLeft + sizeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` can never be `null` inside the running class. You'll be getting a NPE because a Node with `left == null` or `right == null` will not be able to call the `size()` code, because the pointer refers to nothing.

Perhaps your code should be more defensive and check if the children are null before attempting to retrieve their size:

```
public int size() {
    int total = 1;
    if (left != null)
        total += left.size();
    if (right != null)
        total += right.size();
    return total;
}
```

Comment: if `this` can never be `null`, the base case (`if (ths == null) { ... }`) should be removed since it is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for spotting, my bad for copypasta